# Spring - Boot Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot app with a application.properties file, and spring data jpa.
in the app I have a external dependency and need to load the Beans of the external Spring project which has a xml based config.
The external xml has its own component scan and its own spring jpa setup to interact with other DB giving that DB properties in Application.properties file, and I am using @ImportResources to inject its bean in the parent app. But when I am doing this spring data jpa is not loading the Interface repository beans.

Problem is it loads the bean of the xml, but fils to load bean of the repository bean of parent project.

*Appconfig.class*

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xx.xx"})
public class AppConfig {

}
```

*ConfigProperties.class*

```
@Configuration
@Import({AppConfig.class})
@ImportResource("classpath:xx-context.xml")
public class ConfigProperties {

}
```

*xx-context.xml* (sample)

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

    <import resource="yy-repository.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:zz-config.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yy.yy" />

    <bean id="bean_id" 
         //defination
    </bean>

    <bean>
        //defination
    </bean>

</beans>
```

*MainApp.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

*Exception*

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

> Field AARepo in com.xx.xx.services.impl.yyImpl required a bean of type
>   'com.xx.x.repository.AARepo' that could not be found.

*Action*

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.xx.xx.repository.AARepo' in your
>   configuration.`

Answer (score 1):

Use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on the top of your `AppConfigClass`

Answer (score 0):

It seems Springboot can't see your Repo Classes. Can you try to add this:
`@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xx.x.repository")` to you Main App class?!

---UPDATE---

To update the full config in your `MainApp`. Can you try this?!

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.xx.x.repository")
@EntityScan("com.xx.x.repository.entity")
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I have tried this still no good. I feel the issue is that @ImportResources loads the component and Datasource of other dependency project and as it has a datasource setup it fails to do it for the parent

Comment: @user1626001: Just update the full config in your MainApp, can you try?!

Answer (score -1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.arcvideo.cloudagent.repo", "com.arcvideo.cloudagent.customer"})
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")

public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig dataSourceConfig = new HikariConfig();
        dataSourceConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");
        dataSourceConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        dataSourceConfig.setDataSourceClassName(env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class"));
        Properties dataSourceProperties = new Properties();
        dataSourceProperties.put("url", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
        dataSourceProperties.put("user", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.username"));
        dataSourceProperties.put("password", env.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password"));
        dataSourceConfig.setDataSourceProperties(dataSourceProperties);

        return new HikariDataSource(dataSourceConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", env.getProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.autoReconnect", env.getProperty("hibernate.autoReconnect"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        additionalProperties.put("javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode", env.getProperty("javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode"));
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", env.getProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics"));
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
}
```